# Why is the timeout function returning the previous state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I know that state changes happen asynchronously, but I tried to get the current state value using a 1 second timeout, my reasoning being that this will allow enough time for the state to update, but the function is still returning the previous state. I'd like to know what causes this.

```
export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = React.useState(1)
 
  function handleChange() {
    setNum(prev => prev + 1)
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(num)
    }, 1000)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleChange}>+</button>
      <p>{num}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not enough time has passed for the state to change?

Comment: The `setTimeout` callback function has a closure around `num`

Comment: This is not the way to catch state update changes. Use an effect hook, ie `useEffect(() => { console.log(num); }, [num])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried server times to do this in the past but unfortunately, I did not find a way to do it.
So, I use this hack, you can make a new function that takes the value of the new state value and return it so you can use it.

```
const [num, _setNum] = useState(1);

  const setNum = (value) => {
    _setNum(value);
    return value;
  };

  function handleChange() {
    const newNum = setNum(num + 1);
    console.log(newNum);
  }
```

or, save the new value in a new variable and use it,
and I think this way is more popular I always see other developers use it

```
const [num, setNum] = useState(1);

  function handleChange() {
    const newNum = num + 1;
    setNum(newNum);
    console.log(newNum);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleChange}>+</button>
      <p>{num}</p>
    </div>
  );
```